# Polymorphic unidirectional relation in Doctrine like in Eloquent?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have notifications on my site and each notification can be related **unidirectionally** to a post or a video.

We need to display *all the notifications* of the website and for each one of them, some information about the related entity (photo or video). I never need to get all the notifications associated to a video, that is why it is unidirectional.

In Eloquent (Laravel), we can do this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

```
posts
    id - integer
    title - string
    body - text

videos
    id - integer
    title - string
    url - string

notifications
    id - integer
    body - text
    notificationable_id - integer
    notificationable_type - string
```

**Now, how to do the same in Doctrine with Symfony?**

I was hoping to reach this kind of code in the end:

```
interface NotificationableInterface {}

class Video implements NotificationableInterface {}
class Post implements NotificationableInterface {}

class Notification {
    ....
    /**
     * @return NotificationableInterface
     */
    public function getRelatedEntity() {
    }
```

**Is this possible with Doctrine and how to implement it?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [This](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) maybe?

Comment: How would you implement it?

Comment: This is still the top search result on Google. Did you ever find a way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using Doctrine's [Single Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) and [Class Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance).

Comment: I considered doing that but, correct me if I'm wrong, in this case I'll have one junction table for each entity:

Comment: For example a NotificationPost table with (notification_id, post_id) and a NotificationVideo with (notification_id, video_id) but I wanted to keep my schema simple with just one table that stores all the notifications. This kind of schema is possible in Laravel, is it with Doctrine?